# blender 3.6 hidden faces still selectable and manipulable

Tags: edit-mode, faces, selection-tools, select

i'm using blender 3.6i'm a newbie, i've searched everywhere but i couldn't find an answer and i'm going mad! I’ve to hide many faces not contiguous in edit mode so i can select and manipulate only visibles (i think it should be the default option) but, for some reason, if i use A key, Split, P loose part, it works on all faces even the hidden ones. I think i’ve accidentally hit some keys combination that change the setting but i can’t figure out what setting and the way to revert it back.

Comment: Can you add images to your question to demonstrate what you are seeing and what you want to do? https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post

Comment: I was able to recreate your issue. But I will need to know what exactly you are trying to achieve in order to answer. So please provide the images

Comment: I suspect this is working as designed. For instance: Subdivide a simple cube and hide one of the faces. Subdivide again and unhide the face (Alt-H). You'll see that the hidden face has been subdivided with all the other faces.

Comment: thanks John and Akshay, i don't have the option for uploading a photo, as soon as i can i'll upload. John i try with cube in a new project  i hid (H) two faces of the cube i selected all (A key) i splitted edge and i converted every faces in objects (P loose geometry) and the two faces hidden were together in one object. In my case instead it happens that, using the cube example, the two hidden faces are converted in two separate objects, as if select all, split edge and P loose geometry work even on hidden faces